# MySql connection from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which communicates with an Arduino Uno with a serial connection and i want to retrieve commands from an online mysql database. I'm a newbie in javascript programming and i can't figure how to access my database through the extension.
This is my php code (it shows the message stored in the database):

```
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
      if (empty($_POST['label'])) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Inserisci la pass!";


        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $pass = '***';

    if ($_POST['label'] == $pass) {

    $cn = mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***");

    mysql_select_db("***", $cn);




$result = mysql_query("SELECT Messaggio FROM tesinafrax ORDER BY numero DESC LIMIT 1"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $queried_mex = $row['Messaggio'];
  echo json_encode($queried_mex);

 } } else {        $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Inserisci la pass!";

       die(json_encode($response));
 }
 exit;
  }else{
?> 

<h1>Inserisci pass</h1> 
<form method="post" action="leggimex.php">
 <input name = "label" type="text"><button name="vedi"
>vedi</button></form>

<?php
 }
 ?>
```

So how do i open the php, write the password in the textbox and parse the json response in order to obtain a string variable on my local chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

You cant (directly) do that. What you *can* do is set up a REST API in PHP and use Ajax from within your Chrome extension to interact with your API.

From a high level the flow would be: (client side) Chrome extension needs string from your database -> send an Ajax request to your PHP API (eg. yourserver/getstring) -> (backend) Your API receives the request and gets the string from your DB -> PHP API returns a JSON response -> (client side) Ajax request completes and now you have the string as a javascript variable.

This might seem like a lot, but it is probably the best way. The good news is that REST API/Javascript is a hugely popular topic and so there are a LOT of great resources out there, it will just take some research.

For your PHP backend I would checkout [SlimPHP](http://www.slimframework.com/). For the Ajax portion you could use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or just vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Ok it doesn't sound too difficult. Anyway, i've got no experience at all with REST APIs and javascript, if you could give me some example code it would be easier for me to get this to work

Comment: You're right, it will be easy to pick up after a bit of reading :). It's tough to post sample code for this since there are so many unknowns. However, [read this tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/) for a good starting point.